# Gravitational acceleration and simple pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, error-analysis, statistics

I have measured period for different lenghts of thread and draw a $T^2 - l$ graph and got $y= 4,0276x+0.0263.$ Then i found gravitational constant (9.80197) using 4.0276 I don't know how to calculate error of gravitational constant.

Answer (score 1):

You are able to see that there is a small error in your answer, as not only is your value of $g$ slightly different to the surface value, but your $+c$ is non-zero when in fact it should be zero.

To calculate the percentage error in any result, one simply does:
$$\text{percentage error}=\frac{|\text{actual value} - \text{experimental value}|}{\text{actual value}} \times 100$$ where the |x| is the modulus function.

This calculation gives you the difference between your answer and the correct answer, and then expresses this difference in terms of a percentage of the correct answer.

Also note that the gravitational constant (big $G$) is not the gravitational field strength (little $g$). The universal gravitational constant is constant everywhere in the universe, but gravitational field strength varies with distance from the object that is generating the gravitational field.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer but i forgot to mention  i have to calculate error using linear least square fit. I dont know how to calculate error of g if i calculated error of a.

Comment: This calculation does not give the experimental uncertainty in the result. It only gives the % difference between the experimental and official values.

Answer (score 0):

If length was zero then period should be zero. Since it is not, you have a small error in the measurements (as expected). From the data force the line to go though the origin and measure the slope (and hence gravity) of each measurement.

Then do statistics on the measured gravity (average + standard deviation) to arrive at your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Least Squares Regression Method gives values for the standard deviations in the parameters $a$, $b$ for the fit $y=a+bx$.

If the software you are using is sufficiently thorough it will provide a value for the Mean Square Error (MSE) in the slope; the Standard Error is the square root of this.

If you are using a spreadsheet the online article [Obtaining Uncertainty Measures on Slope and Intercept of a Least Squares Fit with Excel’s LINEST](http://www.chem.mtu.edu/~fmorriso/cm3215/UncertaintySlopeInterceptOfLeastSquaresFit.pdf) gives details of how to calculate standard deviation in slope.

This is really a statistical problem rather than physics, and further help can be obtained, for example, from [Cross-Validated SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44838/how-are-the-standard-errors-of-coefficients-calculated-in-a-regression). Alterntively, see the wikipedia article on [Simple Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression#Normality_assumption) in which a formula is given for the *standard error in the estimator for slope* $b$.